# iOS 9 XCode Export without Provisioning Profile - Developer Deployment/Adhoc

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, over-the-air

I've always only been able to "side load" my app on others phones by obtaining their UUID, adding to devices and selectin to be part of the provisioning profile. Have been doing this through over the air deployment via a website. That's all worked great however it's annoying to do.

With iOS9/XCode7 I feel there is a new option to export as Developer Deployment. Does that allow me to load the app on others phones WITHOUT having to obtain their UUID? I've tested this on a friends new phone and initially it hasn't worked.

Is there anyway other way to load the app? Do I still have to get the UUID and export as adhoc deployment? I really hope not...come on Apple!

Comment: I seriously doubt Apple would have relaxed this restriction.  They need to control how many people can get working copies of your app and that is done via the devices being registered to your developer account.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply...so what is the point of "save for developer deployment"? Also why do they need to control that? I feel like they could still understand who has installed the "developer" version if that's really needed without making you register every single device. FYI wrote a script when my beta build is ready which builds the IPA then automatically uploads it to my dropbox site for OTA deployment.

Comment: I don't know what that does, to be honest.  Apple would want to control the number of developer installs as otherwise you could distribute apps to as many people as you liked and completely circumvent the App Store.  If you are happy to wait 48 hours or so, for a beta review, you could distribute your Beta's via their TestFlight framework, which is what I do.  For that you just need your distribution certificate and PP and you don't need to manage UDIDs.  It's also a good rehearsal for the *big day*.

Answer (score 0):

> I feel there is a new option to export as Developer Deployment

You mean, Develop**ment** Deployment? If yes, this is for internal testing, as noted [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/ExportingYouriOSApp.html). (See: [internal vs. external testers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28802962/1289683)).

To test your builds without giving your users technical roles and/or waiting for beta review, use [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/ios) (formerly known as Crashlytics). You don't need to obtain UUIDs manually, this process is managed by their app.