# Do I need to add UDID for internal users in itunesconnect to member center

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, udid

Do I need to add UDID for internal users in itunesconnect to member center.
I know that I don't need to add them for external testers? But what's about internal?
P.S. You can do that here in itunesconnect http://take.ms/7JEPF

Comment: UDID is no longer needed. Invitations are now sent via apple testflight to email IDs which even don't need to match to apple IDs of testers. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802883/difference-between-internal-and-external-testers-in-itunes-testflight-beta-testi

Comment: There is no need to add UDID for internal tester and external tester.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internal Testers must be assigned the Technical or Admin role in iTunes Connect, and you can only have 25 of them. These users need to be at least Technical users:

The technical role grants the ability to edit the app information stored in iTunes Connect and to view test accounts for certain app services. The technical role also grants permission to upload a binary to iTunes Connect and submit an app to App Review. If you don't trust someone with these privileges, they aren't "Internal", they're "External".

UDID is not needed. Just invite using email ID's.